# Copying a Timestamp object's value to another object

Tags: java, object, time, calendar, timestamp

I have a date in Java.sql.Timestamp object (variable-> confirmedDeliveryDate), i wanted to create a different object and add a few days to it. I created ts as a different timestamp variable and I used the following logic. I am able to add days successfully. But as soon as ts gets updated with new time, confirmedDeliveryDate is also updating with the new date. When I have created a  new object for ts why is confirmedDeliveryDate being updated. And please suggest solution for the same.

```
            Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(0L);

            ts=confirmedDeliveryDate;

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(ts);
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
            ts.setTime(cal.getTime().getTime());
            ts = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By coding

```
        ts=confirmedDeliveryDate;
```

You throw away your freshly created timestamp and replace it with the reference to `confirmedDeliveryDate`

So now ts and confirmedDeliveryDate  are **one and the same** and by callling setTime on one of them, the value for both variable names (referencing the **same object**) will change.

Try like this:

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(confirmedDeliveryDate );
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);

        Timestamp ts = new  Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i was making the same mistake.